# Importing data from csv in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

I have a CSV file that contains 4000 columns and I need to import it to a postgres database. I am using pgadminIII. In ORACLE SQL, there is an option where I can right click on the table and import. Is there any similar way in Postgres. If not what is the most effective way to create a table with so many columns?

Update- I got it working:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/dbharali0376/Desktop/Merge_N_Reorder/ip_merged_52_final.csv',dtype='unicode')
df.columns = [c.lower() for c in df.columns] 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres')

df.to_sql("trial", engine, if_exists='append',index=False)
```

This creates a new table from the input csv.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: Are you sure that you can do it with Oracle? As I remember, it have 1000 columns per table limitation. However, PostgreSQL also not so "rubber" and have [Maximum Columns per Table 250 - 1600 depending on column types](https://www.postgresql.org/about/) limitation.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, for COPY i already need a table to exist. IS there a way to create a table with that many columns through GUI, or do i have to type in each column name.

Comment: There is no way at all, since that's too many columns.

Answer (score 0):

What do the columns represent? Is it timestamps or something else that would be better represented in a relational database as rows?

My guess is that you're going to have to manipulate that CSV somehow into something that postgres can handle.

"pgfutter" is a python script that will create the table for you based on the CSV header and then load the data using the COPY command. It's not a GUI tool but should be simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

In PGAdmin III

1. Go to the Tables option in your schema.
2. Right click on your table under, Tables and click on import.
3. Browse the crv file, click on format and select crv.
4. Customize your import - Encoding/Delimter etc.

Comment: That works only if there is a table already created. I updated my question. I found the slution